Log4j2 No inject constructor error when launching through java.exe
I have a program in java made through maven and packaged with assembly into a single jar with all the dependencies. I need to run this in docker so I need to be able to launch it with java.exe. The issue is that log4j2 throws and error. I have found a post with the same error as me and there is an answer. Unfortunately I do not understand what the answer is trying to say and I don't have the reputation to add a comment and ask for clarification.
No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException with Log4J?
This is the error:
PS C:\Users\pholub\eclipse testing\image-resizing-tool\rescaler> C:\DEV_HOME\TOOLS\java\1.17.0_5\bin\java.exe -jar .\target\rescaler-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar                                         
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: org.apache.logging.log4j.plugins.di.NotInjectableException: No @Inject constructor or default constructor found for chain Key[type: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.InterpolatorFactory] -> Key[type: java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.function.Supplier<org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.StrLookup>>; namespace: Lookup]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.plugins.di.DefaultInstanceFactory.createDefaultFactory(DefaultInstanceFactory.java:133)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.plugins.di.DefaultInstanceFactory.lambda$getFactory$3(DefaultInstanceFactory.java:111)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.plugins.di.DefaultInstanceFactory.getFactory(DefaultInstanceFactory.java:111)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.plugins.di.InstanceFactory.getInstance(InstanceFactory.java:126)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.plugins.di.DefaultInstanceFactory.lambda$getArgumentFactory$9(DefaultInstanceFactory.java:211)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:575)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:616)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:622)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.plugins.di.DefaultInstanceFactory.lambda$registerBundleMethod$13(DefaultInstanceFactory.java:293)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.plugins.di.InstanceFactory.getInstance(InstanceFactory.java:115)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.<init>(AbstractConfiguration.java:185)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration.<init>(DefaultConfiguration.java:41)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<init>(LoggerContext.java:89)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.createContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:289)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:240)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:148)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:131)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:125)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:156)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:49)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:127)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:554)
        at gk.tools.rescaler.App.<clinit>(App.java:55)

This is my pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>gk.tools.rescaler</groupId>
  <artifactId>rescaler</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>

  <name>rescaler</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0-beta2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0-beta2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
      <version>1.82</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.downgoon</groupId>
      <artifactId>marvin</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.5</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.downgoon</groupId>
      <artifactId>MarvinFramework</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.downgoon</groupId>
      <artifactId>MarvinPlugins</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.coobird</groupId>
      <artifactId>thumbnailator</artifactId>
      <version>0.4.20</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.imgscalr</groupId>
      <artifactId>imgscalr-lib</artifactId>
      <version>4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>gk.tools.rescaler.App</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <mainClass>gk.tools.rescaler.App</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
              <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                <goals>
                  <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>

And the error is on line with this code:
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(App.class)

edit: also including my log4j2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appenders>

    <File name="ConciseLog" fileName="logs/app.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
      <Filters>
        <ThresholdFilter level="info"/>
      </Filters>
    </File>

    <File name="DebugLog" fileName="logs/app-debug.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
      <Filters>
        <ThresholdFilter level="debug"/>
      </Filters>
    </File>

    <File name="TraceLog" fileName="logs/app-trace.log" append="false">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>

    <Console name="ErrorConsole" target="SYSTEM_OUT"> 
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
      <Filters>
        <ThresholdFilter level="error"/>
      </Filters>
    </Console>
  </appenders>

  <loggers>
    <root level="trace">
      <appender-ref ref="DebugLog"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ConciseLog"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ErrorConsole"/>
      <appender-ref ref="TraceLog"/>
    </root>
  </loggers>

</configuration>

Sorry if this is considered duplication, but I'm not able to figure this out. From what I can understand I need to add something into the classpath, but I can't find what exactly is needed to be added. I have found that log4j2 ignores the classpath command line argument, but I don't know what to do with that information. I think I get the fact that I need to add external jar files into classpath, but everything should be included.

show your log4j2.xml file.

Not very important, but something I would avoid: Generally speaking, the directory paths of my java projects will not contain whitespace characters or special symbols.

That folder is just a remnant of a worse time. I can just pull the repo again, but I had other issues to solve before the ugly folder. Thanks for the reminder though I will keep it in mind.

Test Command: in your project root, run comands: (1) mvn clean package (2) mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=target/libs (3) java -cp "target/libs/*:target/rescaler-1.0.0.jar" gk.tools.rescaler.App

Everything works, until the 3rd one. Error: Could not find or load main class gk.tools.rescaler.App

Sorry , For Windows (3) java -cp "target\libs\*;target\rescaler-1.0.0.jar" gk.tools.rescaler.App

Great, That works! Just so I know what has happened. The .jar gets created, then the dependencies are copied into it and finally it's run with modified classpath which includes all the dependencies.

@life888888: Can you add your comment as answer?

Because I have tested log4j2.xml and the dependent log4j version, the test results seem to be OK.
Then the possible problem may be the encapsulated jar file.
Since I don't have the complete project content, the easiest way is to test it without encapsulating it into an Uber Jar in the following way.
package
mvn clean package
download dependencies jar files to target/libs
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=target/libs
Run App
For Windows
java -cp "target\libs\*;target\rescaler-1.0.0.jar" gk.tools.rescaler.App

Log4j (and many other libraries) uses ServiceLoader to find additional components.
The Maven Assembly Plugin you are using is not able to properly generate an Uber JAR: whenever it encounters two resources with the same name, it drops one of them. Since all the ServiceLoader descriptor files for a given service have the same name (META-INF/services/<fully qualified service name), all but one will be dropped.
To generate an Uber JAR I would recommend:

Using the Spring Boot Maven plugin (see Packaging Executable Archives).
By using it you don't need to know anything about the internals of your dependencies, since this plugin does not break the JAR files.

Spring Boot Maven plugin adds a small 200 KiB dependency to your application.
If this is not acceptable, you can use Apache Maven Shade plugin and choose the right resource transformers (see Resource Transformers).
For your application you need at least the ServiceResourceTransformer and ManifestResourceTransformer:
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <transformers>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
            <manifestEntries>
              <Main-Class>gk.tools.rescaler.App</Main-Class>
              <Multi-Release>true</Multi-Release>
            </manifestEntries>
          </transformer>
        </transformers>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>




You answer is indeed valid. But I would also just love to point out that @life888888 gave an amazing answer in the comments to the original post. It does not create an uber jar, but it worked and is quite simple with understandable logic. (I would love to add it as a second answer, but I don't know how)
